# How can I change the "From" email address without a non-authenticated SMTP server?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, email, smtp

All,

I'm writing an application that will allow customers to submit support tickets directly from their desktop. That being said, I'd like the "FROM" email address to be *their* email address.

I currently have the following code:

```
public void SendTicketEmail()
    {
        try
        {
            string tEmail = materialListView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
            string tPhone = materialListView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;
            string tUser = materialListView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(tEmail, "my email");
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Port = 25;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Host = "smtp.simplifymsp.com";
            mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";
            mail.Body = "this is my test email body";
            client.Send(mail);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
```

I'm assuming that my resolution at this point is to request that my hosting service enable an option where I can allow smtp outgoing emails without authentication on a specified port?

The alternative here is to have all of the support emails from each customer come from one of my preset email addresses and include a Customer ID in the subject, then create a workflow in my helpdesk ticketing system for each customer that assigns the  customer's information to that ticket. That's more work than I care to do, especially when scaling.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is *your* app, creating tickets for *your* system. Instead of distributing  SMTP credential in desktop app (which can be abused easily), why not just create a webservice to directly add a ticket in your system, where you can include the information right where they need it?

Comment: That's a wonderful idea in theory, but not so much in practice. The system wasn't created by me (I pay for a helpdesk ticketing system) and it doesn't integrate well with 3rd party applications.

Comment: FreshService have the API to [create ticket](http://api.freshservice.com/#create_ticket). Also consider that some ISP blocks all SMTP except [their own](http://www.postcastserver.com/help/port_25_blocking.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I resolved this issue rather simply. FreshService (the website that I use for my ticketing system) reacts well with the following code:

```
mail.From = new MailAddress("me@me.com", "customer@customer.com");
```

Even though the email is coming from "me@me.com," FreshService still reads the ticket as if it came from the customer. Works beautifully.

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: It's your question, but in your shoes I'm not sure I'd settle for this, since you can't just reply to those messages. But I suppose the alternative means running your own mail server, which isn't an endeavor for the faint of heart.

Comment: For whatever reason, FreshService sees the email coming from the customer's email address, so I can actually reply to it. It's an odd occurrence, but I'll take it.